# UIStackView not arranging sub views correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a `UIStackView` constrained within a basic `UIView` to fill the whole space.  The stack view axis is vertical, the Alignment is `Fill` and the Distribution is `Fill Equally`.

I've added two container views and set their background colors to be red & green respectively.

[Main Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WE96.png)

All I want is for each subview to fill up half of the space vertically, but for whatever reason it keeps coming out like so:

[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ueft.png)

The container view mode is `Scale To Fill`.

Any ideas?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I write something like this. Everything works fine. Do you forget to set constraint for stackView?

Comment: Thanks @NickAllen, it was indeed fine, just in the wrong size class.  I'm still not comfortable with using size classes, so they keep causing random issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, it was due to `Size Classes`.  I was set to `Compact` when I created the view and the containers.  When I switched back to the base size class (Any, Any), the `UIStackView` was greyed out.  So I rebuilt it from scratch it now it works.

I hope this helps someone else!